# Printing floating points in python

Tags: python, variables, printing, point, floating

How can i print a variable whose value is a floting number?

Eg.

```
my_height = 1.75 #meters
print "I'm %s meters tall." % my_height
```

Why is the return 1 instead of 1.75, and how can i change it?

Comment: The string format argument you're using `%d` is for use in (decimal) integer numbers. Use `%f` instead.

Comment: Just because it can be fixed with one letter doesn't mean that it was a typo. This should not have been closed. It is a genuine problem that can be reproduced? Yes. Was it a typo? No, it was caused by not yet knowing a piece of relevant programming information. I'd say this is perfectly on-topic and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `%f` instead:

```
my_height = 1.75 #meters
>>> print "I'm %f meters tall." % my_height
I'm 1.750000 meters tall.
```

To specify a certain precision, you do it as:

```
my_height = 1.75 #meters
>>> print "I'm %.2f meters tall." % my_height   #the 2 denoting two figures after decimal point
I'm 1.75 meters tall.
```

Comment: Thanks, I just started learning python and it's my first language so I'm kinda lost

Answer (score 4):

Because in string formatting, just like in C, `%d` gives an integer.

To fix it, you need to use `%f` instead of `%d`:

```
print "I'm %f meters tall." % my_height
# Outputs "I'm 1.75 meters tall."
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using %d for displaying a floating point number. You can try below methods for displaying floating point numbers with precision. Method 2 is preferred for python 3 and above

**Method 1:**
`print "I'm %.2f meters tall." % my_height`

**Method 2:**
`print "I'm {:.2f} meters tall.".format(my_height)`